# Is there a way to save an inline shape from docx as an image file?

Tags: python, image, docx, shapes

I'm trying to parse a docx file using python-docx. The file contains images and text. Basically i need a way to take an image(an InlineShape object) from the file and save it as a separate image (like "smth.jpg"). Is there a way to do that?  From reading the API docs it doesn't seem like it, but maybe i'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docx2python` will pull these images for you.

```
from docx2python import docx2python

content = docx2python('my_document.docx', 'output_image_directory')
```

The images will be in whatever directory you supply.

Comment: So... It will pull out all the images out of the docx? Well, i can do that myself by unpacking the docx as an archive. If this lib has a way of determining where the images are located in the text, that'd really help

Comment: The lib will place the string '----image1.jpg----' in the text wherever the image was located

Answer (score 0):

OK, i've figured put a way. Converting docx file to zip and extracting from there. It's not the best option, but still pretty good for me.